# Is there any good reason to send a text version of HTML emails?

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

It's been years since I haven't seen, or heard of, any email client which wouldn't be capable of reading, and displaying, HTML.

I'm in the process of creating email templates for a new website, and wondering if it's worth the effort to try to provide a text version of every automated email sent.

To put things simply, **is there still any good reason to send a text version along with HTML emails?**

Comment: While most email clients probably support html emails, i think a lot of people still choose to turn that feature off. Also often images won't be displayed immediately, since this seems to be the default configuration with most email clients. So, if doable, just make sure that your information is still more or less readable with html and/or image fancy-schmanz turned off.

Comment: That's a wise advice indeed, the HTML should be readable with images turned off. That said, I doubt many people "turn off" HTML; TBH, I don't even know how to do that myself in my mail client, Outlook.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right about the HTML part :D
I mostly thought of the images.

Comment: I've found some good reasons to keep doing it on the [MailChimp blog](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-bother-with-plain-text-emails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text version will definitely reduce the likelihood of your message ending up in spam, and will be friendlier to user agents that can't or won't display HTML. A text version can be generated automatically from the HTML by most email libraries.

Why purposefully alienate some users when the alternative doesn't cost any more work?

Comment: Because automated HTML-to-text conversion is the poor man's solution to this problem. I'd rather have done the opposite (text to HTML in a template, with link replacements), or just plain HTML with no text version: why just blindly remove the markup from some HTML, a job that a spam detection engine will do by itself anyway? That's just my thought, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if this option is available in your subscribe form. If this isn't the case, there's no reason to spend time or money to create a text version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the important part of sending an email campaigns to clients. You need to make sure that you have  a text version also in case the  rendering client is not able to handle html pieces. This helps to make sure that you are at least not spamming as well. Also almost all of the marketing email engines have a default option to convert the html email into text version if you don't specify the text version.